# How to draw HCURSOR on transparent background?

Tags: windows, winapi

How to draw `HCURSOR` on some surface filled with transparent color, so only cursor will be drawn and no background will be filled with black color. I want to iterate some surface pixel-by-pixel to check its color and skip transparent part.

Consider I have only:

```cpp
CURSORINFO cursor = { sizeof( cursor ) };

if( GetCursorInfo( &cursor ) && cursor.flags == CURSOR_SHOWING )
    ...
```

I know about `DrawIcon()` and `DrawIconEx()` functions, but they draw black background. Look:

```cpp
CURSORINFO cursor = { sizeof( cursor ) };

if( GetCursorInfo( &cursor ) && cursor.flags == CURSOR_SHOWING )
{
    ICONINFO info = { sizeof( info ) };

    if( GetIconInfo( cursor.hCursor, &info ) )
    {
        HWND hWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
        HDC hDC = GetWindowDC( hWnd );
        HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC( hDC );
        BITMAP bmpCursor = { 0 };
        GetObject( info.hbmColor ? info.hbmColor : info.hbmMask,
            sizeof( bmpCursor ), &bmpCursor );
        HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdcMem, bmpCursor.bmWidth, bmpCursor.bmHeight );
        auto original = SelectObject( hdcMem, hBitmap );
        RECT br;
        br.left = br.top = 0;
        br.right = bmpCursor.bmWidth;
        br.bottom = bmpCursor.bmHeight;
        HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush( RGB( 1, 1, 1 ) );
        FillRect( hdcMem, &br, hBrush );
        DeleteObject( hBrush );
        DrawIconEx( hdcMem, 0, 0, cursor.hCursor, 0, 0, 0, nullptr, DI_DEFAULTSIZE | DI_NORMAL );

        QImage img( bmpCursor.bmWidth, bmpCursor.bmHeight, QImage::Format_ARGB32 );
        img.fill( Qt::transparent );

        std::set< COLORREF > s;

        for( int x = 0; x < bmpCursor.bmWidth; ++x )
        {
            for( int y = 0; y < bmpCursor.bmHeight; ++y )
            {
                COLORREF c = GetPixel( hdcMem, x, y );
                s.insert( c );

                if( c != RGB( 1, 1, 1 ) )
                {
                    auto qc = QColor( QRgba64::fromArgb32( c ) );
                    qc.setAlpha( 255 );
                    img.setPixelColor( x, y, qc );
                }
            }
        }

        cursorPos = r.intersects( { QPoint( cursor.ptScreenPos.x - info.xHotspot,
                    cursor.ptScreenPos.y - info.yHotspot ),
                QSize( bmpCursor.bmWidth, bmpCursor.bmHeight ) } ) ?
            QPoint( cursor.ptScreenPos.x - info.xHotspot - r.x(),
                cursor.ptScreenPos.y - info.yHotspot - r.y() ) :
            QPoint( -1, -1 );
        w = cursorPos.x() != -1 ? bmpCursor.bmWidth : 0;
        h = cursorPos.y() != -1 ? bmpCursor.bmHeight : 0;
        cursorImage = img.copy();

        if( info.hbmMask )
            DeleteObject( info.hbmMask );

        if( info.hbmColor )
            DeleteObject( info.hbmColor );

        SelectObject( hdcMem, original );

        DeleteDC( hdcMem );
        DeleteObject( hBitmap );

    }

    if( cursor.hCursor )
        DeleteObject( cursor.hCursor );
}
```

But in `std::set` `s` I see only `0` and `FFFFFF` values, `DrawIconEx` replaced all `RGB( 1, 1, 1 )` pixels with `0`...

How to avoid this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawicon

Comment: @GSerg I know about this function, I edited my question...

Comment: `CreateCompatibleDC` gives you a DC with a default 1x1 monochrome bitmap selected into it; calling `CreateCompatibleBitmap` on that DC then returns a monochrome bitmap as well. You need to use your window's DC in the call to `CreateCompatibleBitmap`.

Comment: As @JonathanPotter and [CreateCompatibleBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createcompatiblebitmap) said, *When a memory device context is created, it initially has a 1-by-1 monochrome bitmap selected into it. If this memory device context is used in CreateCompatibleBitmap, the bitmap that is created is a monochrome bitmap. To create a color bitmap, use the HDC that was used to create the memory device context,* see [Capturing an Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question. Thanks, guys, for comments, you really helped.

Most important thing in this question is that `DrawIcon()` and `DrawIconEx()` functions consider the backgraound on what they paint icon or cursor. So if you wish to have an image of cursor you should paint it on the background on what the cursor appears on the desktop to be it correctly drawn, because a color of cursor may change depending on what background it should be drawn.

So, knowing this the problem solves very easy. Consider in the following code
`const QRect & r` is a rectangle of the area in the global coordinates where you want to make a screenshot, and `const QImage & i` is a screenshot of that area, having these we can implement function `grabMouseCursor()` that will return a `QImage` of cursor, just cursor, without any background.

```cpp
QPair< QImage, QRect >
grabMouseCursor( const QRect & r, const QImage & i )
{
    QImage cursorImage;
    QPoint cursorPos( -1, -1 );
    int w = 0;
    int h = 0;

#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    // auto display = QApplication::platformNativeInterface();

    Display* display = XOpenDisplay( nullptr );

    XFixesCursorImage * cursor = XFixesGetCursorImage( display );

    cursorPos = r.intersects( { QPoint( cursor->x - cursor->xhot, cursor->y - cursor->yhot ),
            QSize( cursor->width, cursor->height ) } ) ?
        QPoint( cursor->x - cursor->xhot- r.x(), cursor->y - cursor->yhot - r.y() ) :
        QPoint( -1, -1 );

    std::vector< uint32_t > pixels( cursor->width * cursor->height );

    w = cursorPos.x() != -1 ? cursor->width : 0;
    h = cursorPos.y() != -1 ? cursor->height : 0;

    for( size_t i = 0; i < pixels.size(); ++i )
        pixels[ i ] = cursor->pixels[ i ];

    cursorImage = QImage( (uchar*)( pixels.data() ), w, h,
        QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied).copy();

    XFree( cursor );

    XCloseDisplay( display );
#elif defined( Q_OS_WINDOWS )
    CURSORINFO cursor = { sizeof( cursor ) };

    if( GetCursorInfo( &cursor ) && cursor.flags == CURSOR_SHOWING )
    {
        ICONINFO info = { sizeof( info ) };

        if( GetIconInfo( cursor.hCursor, &info ) )
        {
            HWND hWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
            HDC hDC = GetWindowDC( hWnd );
            HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC( hDC );
            BITMAP bmpCursor = { 0 };
            GetObject( info.hbmColor ? info.hbmColor : info.hbmMask,
                sizeof( bmpCursor ), &bmpCursor );
            HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hDC, bmpCursor.bmWidth, bmpCursor.bmHeight );
            auto original = SelectObject( hdcMem, hBitmap );

            const QPoint ctl( cursor.ptScreenPos.x - info.xHotspot,
                cursor.ptScreenPos.y - info.yHotspot );
            w = bmpCursor.bmWidth;
            h = bmpCursor.bmHeight;

            for( int x = 0; x < w; ++x )
            {
                for( int y = 0; y < h; ++y )
                {
                    const QPoint c = QPoint( x, y ) + ctl;

                    if( r.contains( c ) )
                    {
                        const auto color = i.pixelColor( c - r.topLeft() );
                        SetPixel( hdcMem, x, y, RGB( color.red(), color.green(), color.blue() ) );
                    }
                }
            }

            DrawIconEx( hdcMem, 0, 0, cursor.hCursor, 0, 0, 0, nullptr, DI_DEFAULTSIZE | DI_NORMAL );

            QImage img( bmpCursor.bmWidth, bmpCursor.bmHeight, QImage::Format_ARGB32 );
            img.fill( Qt::transparent );

            for( int x = 0; x < w; ++x )
            {
                for( int y = 0; y < h; ++y )
                {
                    const QPoint c = QPoint( x, y ) + ctl;

                    if( r.contains( c ) )
                    {
                        const auto winColor = GetPixel( hdcMem, x, y );
                        const auto color1 = i.pixelColor( c - r.topLeft() );
                        const auto color2 = QColor( GetRValue( winColor ),
                            GetGValue( winColor ), GetBValue( winColor ) );

                        if( color1 != color2 )
                            img.setPixelColor( x, y, color2 );
                    }
                }
            }

            cursorPos = r.intersects( { ctl, QSize( w, h ) } ) ?
                ctl - r.topLeft() : QPoint( -1, -1 );
            w = cursorPos.x() != -1 ? w : 0;
            h = cursorPos.y() != -1 ? h : 0;
            cursorImage = img.copy();

            if( info.hbmMask )
                DeleteObject( info.hbmMask );

            if( info.hbmColor )
                DeleteObject( info.hbmColor );

            SelectObject( hdcMem, original );

            DeleteDC( hdcMem );
            DeleteObject( hBitmap );
        }

        if( cursor.hCursor )
            DeleteObject( cursor.hCursor );
    }
#endif

    return { cursorImage, { cursorPos, QSize( w, h ) } };
}
```